# Lightning Standard tabs switching

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-community

I have added 2 standard lightning tabs.
I have different components in each.
I want to navigate from one tab to another on click of a button. Is it possible in standard tabs? The button is in the one component. 
I want to open the 2nd tab when button of the first tab is clicked.
Tabs are standard.

Comment: please share what and how you are attempting to do so, if you are facing a problem codewise, please incldue your code, and where you are stuck. please mention what interface you are using? LEX, Community, adding all the tags doesnt really help narrow down where you are facing this issue

Comment: I think it would not possible. You can try with creating new component with lightning:tabset and put your component there